# Setting the 'name' property of a Form in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

Referring to the Codeigniter user guide at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html, I cannot seem to figure out how to set the 'name' property of a form using CI's form helper. Only 'id' can be set by passing an array in. Can the 'name' of the form be set without passing an array to the form_open() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name attribute for a form is actually deprecated:

> > 17.3 The FORM element
>
> [....]
>
> ```
> name = cdata [CI]
>     This attribute names the element so that it may be referred to
> ```
>
> from style sheets or scripts. Note.
>   This attribute has been included for
>   backwards compatibility. Applications
>   should use the id attribute to
>   identify elements.

Source: [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)

If you really want to pass it, I fear you have no choice but using the array you want to avoid, as you read in the manual.

Comment: Good to know! Just wondering if there is any major difference between using 'name' and 'id', maybe 'name' is still being used for the older browsers?

Comment: @Nyxynyx sounds like it's like that! Anyway, ID is more practical, as you can easily attach js handlers, css classes and so on. Besides, there's nothing to retrieve from server side in a <form> (not inputs, of course), so I don't see why using it ;)

Comment: I wonder why the name attribute would be deprecated, when it is extremely useful to call the form name as an associative array element in javascript:

   `document.forms['myform']`

Comment: Why not the more direct and straightforward `document.getElementById('myformid')`? Why are you against that?

Answer (score 7):

you can use this method

```
$attributes = array('name' => 'myform');

echo form_open('email/send', $attributes);
```

Comment: i don't know why my answer is down voted ... as w3school also use the name attribute with form tag .. [w3 school example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_name.asp)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I assume it has been done because your solution uses an array, and OP asked for a non-array solution, but I might be wrong on downvoter's intentions..

Comment: @Damien Pirsy, the OP said this: "Only 'id' can be set by passing an array in." But that is not true. If his question is based on the premise that the name attribute may not be passed to the form helper using an array, then it is an irrelevant question, because cchameed has demonstrated that the name can be passed to the form helper by using an array. I just used this method in my form, and now I see a name attribute where there wasn't one before.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but `Can the 'name' of the form be set without passing an array to the form_open()` means OP doesn't want to pass an array, period. I conclude the question is misleading

Comment: Right, he asked that. But it seemed he asked under the premise that it couldn't be done using an array, which is not true now (maybe it was two years ago when he asked the question).

Comment: No one said it wasn't possible, I even said that: `If you really want to pass it, I fear you have no choice but using the array you want to avoid` . Really I don't know what you're arguing on